# number of zeros/rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

let
$h(z)=z^5+\frac{1}{3}z^3+\frac{1}{4}z^2+\frac{1}{3}$
the numbers of zeros on $M$ should be determined with
$M=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < \frac{1}{2}\}$.

So I tried to apply Rouche's theorem:
with $g(z)=z^5+\frac{1}{3}z^3$ amd $f(z)=\frac{1}{4}z^2+\frac{1}{3}$, I checked on the boundary $|z|=1/2$, so $|g(z)|=|z^5+\frac{1}{3}z^3| \leq \frac{7}{96} \leq |f(z)| \leq \frac{38}{96}$

so can I deduct from this that $f+g (:=h)$ and $f$ must have the same zeros in $M=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < \frac{1}{2}\}$? and that  would reduce the problem to solving

$\frac{1}{4}z^2+\frac{1}{3}=0$? (the only solutions here would not fulfill $|z| \leq 1/2$) so can I conclude that $h$ would not be having any zeros on $|z| \leq 1/2$?

Comment: triangle inequality is enough since $|h(z)| \ge 1/3-1/32-1/24-1/16 >0$

Comment: besides, $f(z)=\frac{1}{4}\left(z^2+\frac{4}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(z+i\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(z-i\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}>1>1/2$. So two of $f$'s zeros are not in $M$. Can $f$ have more than two zeros?

Comment: @MAPelto: thanks, since f is of grade 2, it can only have two zeros?

Comment: @Conrad: I do not quite understand, what did you use as input for $z$ because why are all the signs of all the terms suddenly negative except that of the constant $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Basically but you should really try to understand Conrad's argument: $|h(z)| =|-1/3-(h(z)-1/3)| \geq \left| \frac{1}{3}- \left| z^5+\frac{1}{3}z^3+\frac{1}{4}z^2 \right| \right| \geq \frac{1}{3}-\left( z^5+\frac{1}{3}z^3+\frac{1}{4}z^2 \right) \\ \geq \frac{1}{3}-\left( 2^{-5}+\frac{1}{3}2^{-3}+\frac{1}{4}2^{-2} \right)=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4}\right)> \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}>.05>0$ $\quad \quad \quad $ whenever $|z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$